# Laravel 5.5 post data to mysqli database via jquery

Tags: jquery, post, mysqli, laravel-5.5, eloquent

Can anyone please help me to how to POST data and save it my PHPMYADMIN mysqli database with Jquery in Laravel 5.5?
I have search so many answers but they were not satisfactory and I cannot make things work.
Can anyone please help me with a simple code with 2 input data types and an image upload input?
 Heres my sample code:
For Blade view Part:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="t-course">Course</span>
        <select id="course" title="course" name="course" class="form-control">
            <option class="form-control">B.A.</option>
            <option class="form-control">B.COM.</option>
            <option class="form-control">M.A.(HISTORY)</option>
            <option class="form-control">M.A.(GUJARATI)</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

For Jquery:

```
$('#AddButton').click(function() {
    var course = $("#course").find("option:selected").val();
    console.log(course);
    $.post('/admissionform',
    {'course':course,'_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()},function () {
        alert('Saved Successfully');
    });
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/admissionform','admissionFormController@create');
```

Controller:

```
public function create(Request $request){
    $course = new studentMainData;
    $course->course = $request->text;
    $course->save();
    activity()->log('User created New Entry');
    return 'ok';
}
```

Please help anyone

Comment: Provide some code..

Comment: Configure "config / database.php" with your phpmyadmin credentials and database name. Create Controller inside "app / Http / Controllers /", Include database dependencies in that and write the function to insert the data. Create proper route for that function which will be an API eventually in "app / Http / routes.php". 

Create your form inside "resources / views /somefile.blade.php" and make an ajax request to your POST API. That's it.

Follow Laravel/Laracast documentation for more details.

Comment: what is the problem with this explaination?https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/ajax-file-upload-with-form-data-laravel-53?page=1

Comment: I have updated the code sajalsuraj sir..